# Calling Script via URL in Home Directory via a Script in the public_html directory doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a script in my home directory I am wanting to run from a remote server, so I set up a script mytestscript.php in the public_html directory with this in it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php


$cat = exec('/usr/local/bin/php /home/example/testfolder/testscript.php',$out,$ret);

print_r($out);

exit;

?>
```

In the testscript.php script I have a simple ffmpeg call:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

echo "hi";

$cat = exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i texas.mp4 -y texas2.mp4',$out,$ret);

print_r($out);

?>
```

When I visit the url in the browser: example.com/mytestscript.php

I get this response in the browser:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php Array ( [0] => hiArray [1] => ( [2] => ) )
```

And the ffmpeg code does not run or make the new video file.

The permissions all match up on the scripts and the video file.

If I copy the ffmpeg code straight into my script in the public_html dir and execute it via URL, the video does encode.

Is there some reason this isn't working?  I am not getting any errors in the logs.

Comment: Use the full path for the video files?

Comment: Just changed that and got the same result.

Comment: Add (space) 2>&1 at the end of your exec cmd. It allow to redirect shell output. And var dump $cat too.